# getting requestattributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jstl

I want to retrieve the request scope attribute in javascript as follows. How can I achieve this?

```
function caseChanges(req) {
    var innervalue= "${dashboardTicketSummary}"
    alert("nand you are 1234");
    alert(innervalue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumin the javascript is included inline on the jsp page -- you're on the right track, you just need to make sure the attribute is set (typically by your controller class) on the HttpServletRequest object, ie:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{
  DashboardTicketSummary dts = ...; // code to obtain ticket summary here

  req.setAttribute("dashboardTicketSummary", dts);

  // code to dispatch to your jsp page here
}
```

Of course there are many other more sophisticated way -- especially is you use popular MVC framework such as Spring

Comment: i am setting it in an action class , i am having issue pulling the value on a jsp page in java script.

Comment: Sorry, My Bad. It was a ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

set value to request attributes and write this piece of code in a script tag on jsp page (like index.jsp):

```
<script>
    function caseChanges(req){
        var innervalue= "${dashboardTicketSummary}"
        alert("nand you are 1234");
        alert(innervalue);
    } 
</script>
```

for better maintainability, you can gathering all attributes to a global object on jsp, and refer to it on other js files:

index.jsp

```
<script>
    var REQUEST_ATTRS = {
            dashboardTicketSummary : '${dashboardTicketSummary}',
            otherAttributes :'${otherAttributes}'
        };
</script>
```

other.js

```
function caseChanges(req){
    var innervalue= REQUEST_ATTRS.dashboardTicketSummary ;
    alert("nand you are 1234");
    alert(innervalue);
}
```